# Backbone js. simple error fetching data from the server

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone, that is why I wrote "simple" in the title, cause this might be an error with a simple solution. I haven't been able to fetch the data from the server and log it.

So, this is the code:

```
TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/times/api/day'
});

var nModel = new TheModel({ id:1 });

nModel.fetch();

console.log(nModel.get("minutes"));
```

The API url is returning a JSON object:

```
curl http://localhost:7000/times/api/day/1 

{"date": "2014-10-25T18:56:32Z", "minutes": 400, "comments": "Tw.Karaoke", "trophy": "", "owner": null}
```

It doesn't log "400", it logs "undefined", why?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fetch operation is asynchronous, so you have to wait till the ajax call is completed

```
nModel.fetch({
         success:function(){ 
            console.log(nModel.get("minutes"));
                 }});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have an extra question.. should I use "success" all the time I fetch data and want to do something with that data? I mean, is this "the way" to do it?.

Comment: @alejoss you can listen for events like sync,reset on model then proceed if you dont want to use success callback